# need help moving a camera in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, camera

I am working on a simple OpenGL project.
I want to get a simple camera to move in perspective mode.

I keep reading about the projection matrix, gluLookAt, and the model view matrix. I keep reading that all I should do are my perspective calls in the projection matrix and then all of my transformations and camera movement in the model view matrix.

```
#include "GLheaders.h"

void drawWorldAxis() {
    glLoadIdentity();
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(1,0,0);
    glColor3ub(0, 255, 0);
    glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(0,1,0);
    glColor3ub(0, 0, 255);
    glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(0,0,1);
    glEnd();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

static float eye[3] = {.5, .5, .5};
#include <stdio.h>
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(55.0, 1, .1, 10000);



    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    drawWorldAxis();
    printf("eye at <%f, %f, %f>\n", eye[0], eye[1], eye[2]);
    fflush(stdout);
    gluLookAt(eye[0], eye[1], eye[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

    eye[0] += .1;
    eye[1] += .1;

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(55.0, 1, -1, 10000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glutPostRedisplay();

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE| GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
    glutCreateWindow("Tiny Test");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am expecting this code to display three lines representing the world coordinate system's x, y, and z axises, and as keys are pressed the camera should move and start to look at the origin/coordinate axises from more and more drastic angles.

What is going wrong here? I've been bashing my head into a wall trying to figure out why nothing is moving. It only changes if I put the gluLookAt call in the projection matrix which I keep being told is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinate cross is drawn **before** you set the lookAt matrix, thus the matrix has no effect.

You have to change the order such that the matrix is already present when drawing:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(eye[0], eye[1], eye[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
drawWorldAxis();
printf("eye at <%f, %f, %f>\n", eye[0], eye[1], eye[2]);
fflush(stdout);
```

Then there is a second problem: You are resetting the model matrix in the first line of `drawWorldAxis`. Here, you can either remove the `glLoadIdentity` call or push the previous matrix to the stack first:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(eye[0], eye[1], eye[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

glPushMatrix();    

drawWorldAxis();

glPopMatrix();

printf("eye at <%f, %f, %f>\n", eye[0], eye[1], eye[2]);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Thanks! this lead me where I needed to go! The loadIdentity was also making it so that I wasn't seeing the worldaxis because the lookAt wasn't being applied to it either. Clearing out the loadIdentity, and reordering things seemed to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @BDL for helping fix this! This is the correct code that I wanted

```
#include "GLheaders.h"

void drawWorldAxis() {
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(1,0,0);
    glColor3ub(0, 255, 0);
    glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(0,1,0);
    glColor3ub(0, 0, 255);
    glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(0,0,1);
    glEnd();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

static float eye[3] = {-.1, -.1, 1};
#include <stdio.h>
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(55.0, 1, .1, 10000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    printf("eye at <%f, %f, %f>\n", eye[0], eye[1], eye[2]);
    fflush(stdout);
    gluLookAt(eye[0], eye[1], eye[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    drawWorldAxis();

    eye[0] += .1;
    eye[1] += .1;

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(55.0, 1, -1, 10000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glutPostRedisplay();

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE| GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
    glutCreateWindow("Tiny Test");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```